# Summing Two Columns from Two Tables with Two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work for a CPG company and need to create a report that compares the previous month's delivered units to the next month's forecast. (Simply, our forecasting tool screws up occasionally and this will help identify when the forecast is off.)

My issue is my SQL query is summing forecast sales correctly, but the sum of total delivered is not respecting the dates I have in my `WHERE` clause -- it's summing total delivered for as far back as the query can reach.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    DelUnits.Customer, DelUnits.ObsText01,
    FinalFcst.SKU, FinalFcst.Customer,
    SUM(DelUnits.Value) AS TotalDelivered,
    SUM(FinalFcst.FinalFcst) AS ForecastSales
FROM 
    DelUnits
LEFT JOIN 
    FinalFcst ON DelUnits.Customer = FinalFcst.Customer
WHERE 
    (FinalFcst.DT >= '2018-01-01' and FinalFcst.DT <= '2018-01-31')
    AND (DelUnits.Date >= '2017-12-01' and DelUnits.Date <= '2017-12-31')
    AND DelUnits.ObsText01 = '10_LB'
    AND FinalFcst.SKU = '10_LB'
GROUP BY 
    DelUnits.Customer, DelUnits.ObsText01, FinalFcst.SKU, FinalFcst.Customer
```

Again, the query seems to work correctly for the final forecast (summing the forecast between 1/1/18 - 1/31/18) but sums the entire delivery history for a customer. I don't understand why it won't sum the delivery history for just 12/1/17 - 12/31/17.

[image: sample data]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The query seems correct, if you remove **sum(FinalFcst.FinalFcst) as ForecastSales** the total is it correct?

Comment: Please add some sample data

Comment: @KashifQureshi thanks for your suggestion. Please see edited post. Still learning what all needs to be included in questions :)

Comment: @TheOni If I remove that line (and the FinalFcst line in the where clause) it still does not sum TotalDelivered correctly.

Comment: you need to sum on both sides before joining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to calculate TotalDelivered and ForecastSales in 2 different queries and then join them together.

Try this:

```
SELECT DelUnits.customer, 
       DelUnits.obstext01, 
       FinalFcst.sku, 
       FinalFcst.customer, 
       totaldelivered, 
       forecastsales 
FROM   (SELECT customer, 
               obstext01, 
               Sum(value) AS TotalDelivered 
        FROM   delunits 
        WHERE  date >= '2017-12-01' 
               AND date <= '2017-12-31'  
               AND obstext01 = '10_LB' 
        GROUP  BY customer, 
                  obstext01) DelUnits 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer, 
                    sku, 
                    Sum(finalfcst) AS ForecastSales 
            FROM   finalfcst 
            WHERE  dt >= '2018-01-01' 
                   AND dt <= '2018-01-31' 
                   AND sku = '10_LB' 
            GROUP  BY customer, 
                    sku) FinalFcst  ON DelUnits.customer = FinalFcst.customer
```

Comment: you'll also want to join `on obstext01=sku`

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, there is only one row for `FinalFcst`.  So, either include it in the `GROUP BY` clause or use `MAX()` instead of `SUM()`:

```
max(FinalFcst.FinalFcst) as ForecastSales
```

Comment: The FinalFcst table actually has multiple rows for each customer... One row per date that includes the forecast for that date. So I would need SUM, correct? MAX would just give me the largest forecast for each customer in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You have a many to many relationship between the tables.  Ultimately you need to `SUM()` one table before joining to the other to create a one to many relationship, or you end up duplicating records.

My favorite approach is a derived table:

```
SELECT C.Customer, 
       C.ObsText01,
       FC.SKU,
       C.TotalDelivered,
       SUM(FC.FinalFcst) ForecastSales
FROM (SELECT SUM(Value) TotalDelivered, Customer, ObsText01
      FROM DelUnits
      WHERE Date >= '2017-12-01' AND Date <= '2017-12-31'
      AND ObsText01 = '10_LB'
      GROUP BY Customer) C
LEFT JOIN FinalFcst FC ON C.Customer = FC.Customer
                      AND FC.DT >= '2018-01-01' 
                      AND FC.DT <= '2018-01-31'
                      AND FC.SKU = '10_LB'
GROUP BY C.Customer, C.ObsText01, FC.SKU, C.TotalDelivered
```

A couple things: Added your forecast table filters to the join predicate, since having those in the `WHERE` will create an `INNER JOIN` out of your `LEFT JOIN`.  Also removed `FC.Customer` from the select and the group since it is redundant with `C.Customer`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to create a temp table to calculate the delivery history. I am not sure of the SQL Server verbiage, but something like this:

```
WITH DEL_HIST AS
(SELECT DelUnits.Customer,
DelUnits.ObsText01,
sum(DelUnits.Value) as TotalDelivered,
FROM DelUnits
Where(DelUnits.Date >= '2017-12-01' and DelUnits.Date <= '2017-12-31')
and DelUnits.ObsText01 = '10_LB'
Group By DelUnits.Customer, DelUnits.ObsText01)
SELECT
DEL_HIST.Customer,
DEL_HIST.ObsText01,
FinalFcst.SKU,
FinalFcst.Customer,
DEL_HIST.TotalDelivered,
sum(FinalFcst.FinalFcst) as ForecastSales
FROM DEL_HIST
left join FinalFcst ON DelUnits.Customer = FinalFcst.Customer
Where (FinalFcst.DT >= '2018-01-01' and FinalFcst.DT <= '2018-01-31')
and FinalFcst.SKU = '10_LB'
Group By DelUnits.Customer, DelUnits.ObsText01, FinalFcst.SKU, FinalFcst.Customer
```

Comment: A CTE is not a temporary table.